# LINQ throwing TypeAs expression with input of type 1 and check of type 2 is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

This line is giving me ***The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type User and a check of type SoftDeleteEntity is not supported***:

```
var test = this.partiallyFiltered.Where(additionalFilter).ToList();
```

Here's what's in there. partiallyFiltered is of type `IQueriable<User>`. Additional filter is of type `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` and the actual expression being passed (as per debugger) is `!((x as SoftDeleteEntity).IsDeleted)`. User inherits SoftDeleteEntity. I don't think I'm missing any relevant information but if I am let me know and I will elaborate. I understand that there must be an implicit cast that doesn't work somewhere but I can't find it.

**Edit:** here's the declaration of the expression, all entities are IEntity.

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> DefaultFilter<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : IEntity
{
   if (typeof(SoftDeleteEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
      return x => !(x as SoftDeleteEntity).IsDeleted;
   else return x => true;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the `as` operator there. Try using a regular cast instead.

Comment: going to try that right now but fyi that ' as ' was there when this code was working. **Edit**: just tried, if i change it to ((SoftDeleteEntity)x) it says "cannot convert TEntity to SoftDeleteEntity".

Comment: You'll have to show use the full code then. You're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: I updated my question with the relevant part

Comment: Does `SoftDeleteEntity` implement `IEntity`?

Comment: SoftDeleteEntity inherits RestrictedEntity which inherits TrackedEntity which inherits RuntimeEntity
And RuntimeEntity implements IEntity, so yes.
Remember that only `!(x as SoftDeleteEntity).IsDeleted` is passed so the rest of the logic in the DefaultFilter declaration obviously works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to do this dynamically. Generics (combined with Entity Framework's apparent fear of typecasting) won't allow you to write the code you want in a static manner. So try this instead:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> DefaultFilter<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
   if (typeof(SoftDeleteEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
      return DefaultFilterSoftDelete<TEntity>();
   else return x => true;
}

public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> DefaultFilterSoftDelete<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression,
        "IsDeleted");
    var notExpression = Expression.Not(propertyExpression);
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(notExpression,
        parameterExpression);

    return lambdaExpression;
}
```

What this code does is dynamically generates the expression you're looking for without having to express a typecast; the expression will already be strongly-typed to the specific entity type (like `User`) when it gets walked by Entity Framework.

**EDIT:** As to why the code *used* to work, the only hazardable explanation is that before the code stopped working as expected, the lambda expression you created in the `DefaultFilter` function was only being run on the client, and not translated to SQL by Entity Framework. Somewhere along the way, code that consumes the filter expression began applying it to an `IQueryable<T>` representing an entity collection, as opposed to an `IEnumerable<T>` (or similar) collection in memory. The code as you presented it would work correctly using LINQ to Objects, but not Entity Framework.

Comment: Upvoting this because that last sentence led me to my solution

Comment: I tried this, and now I get "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." in the same line as I used to get the originall TypeAs exception

Comment: That means that one of your lambda expressions being passed to Entity Framework is calling a function that can't be translated to SQL. Inspect your expression to find out what that is.

Comment: This is the inspected expression `.Lambda #Lambda1<Func'2[User,Boolean]>(user $var1) { !$var1.IsDeleted }` Why wouldn't this be translatable to SQL? IsDeleted is the name of a BIT column btw.

Comment: When you're applying the `Where` function to your `partiallyFiltered` collection, are you using the syntax `partiallyFiltered.Where(expression)` or `partiallyFiltered.Where(x => expression(x))`? Because only the first will work. You need to pass the lambda expression as-is, not wrap it in another expression.

Comment: As is `this.partiallyFiltered.Where(additionalFilter).ToList()`

Comment: Then perhaps the filter that produces the `partiallyFiltered` collection in the first place has an unsupported expression in its chain. How is that collection generated?

Comment: Turns out my previous filter still had the ".Compile()" from my earlier test. Sorry about that. Your solution works. I guess I'll have to learn how to write these expressions using the Expression object for my other filter cause it looks quite convoluted. I wish there was a simpler solution.

Comment: I love when you Google an exception and the answer is your exact use case :D

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with the answer, inspired by Adam's answer. The solution I came up with is the following:

```
var function = additionalFilter.Compile();
var test = this.partiallyFiltered.Where(x => function(x));
```

This code is only used once per entity type so compiling it here doesn't seem to be an issue. This seems to be the less cumbersome solution or the one that requires the less duplication compared to the other suggested solutions so I will accept it in 2 days unless someone else comes up with the real reason why my code that used to work for the longest time stopped working. This code works but it doesn't explain anything, and Adam's explanation makes perfect sense except my statically defined filter was working before and I can see from my history that its code was never modified. Only my model has been modified.

**Edit:** As noted by adams, the compiled filter won't be translated to sql (what was I thinking) and thus will only run locally, so this is no answer after all

Comment: I added an edit to my answer with the likely cause of the change in behavior. Perhaps you can check your revision logs to confirm this.

Comment: @AdamMaras with that in mind, do you see a reason not to use the compiled function like i did?

Comment: Yes, using the compiled expression will force the filter clause to be run by your application, instead of being passed to Entity Framework for translation to SQL. Imagine if you have a thousand records, and 990 of the have the `IsDeleted` flag set to `true`. With the compiled expression, the database server will return all 1,000 rows, and your application must filter out the 990 that are deleted. With the uncompiled expression, Entity Framework can indicate to SQL Server using a `WHERE` clause that only the 10 records with the flag set to `false` should be returned.