# Is it possible to return different models in an ODataController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

IN a OData v4 Controller, is it possible to return different models for the `Get()` and the `Get([FromIDataUri] key)`?

I like to use ViewModels, and when using the `Get()` method I'd like to return an `xxxOverviewViewModel`. When using the `Get([FromIDataUri] key)` method, I'd like to return a xxxViewModel.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

I've tried to return different models, but I always get a `406 Acceptable`.

Webapi.config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<ComplaintViewModel>("ComplaintOData");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();

    }
}
```

ComplaintODataController

```
public class ComplaintODataController : ODataController
{
    private readonly QueryProcessor _queryProcessor;

    public ComplaintODataController(QueryProcessor queryProcessor)
    {
        _queryProcessor = queryProcessor;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ComplaintOverviewViewModel> Get()
    {
        var result = _queryProcessor.Handle(new GetAllComplaintsQuery());
        return result;
    }

    // WHEN CALLING THIS METHOD I GET A 406: 
    [EnableQuery]
    public ComplaintViewModel Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        var result = _queryProcessor.Handle(new GetComplaintByIdQuery { Id = key });
        return result;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

My `GetAllComplaintsQuery.Handle` method looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<ComplaintOverviewViewModel> Handle(GetAllComplaintsQuery query)
{
    // .All is an IQueryable<Complaint>
    var result = _unitOfWork.Complaints.All.Select(c => new ComplaintOverviewViewModel
    {
        ComplaintType = c.ComplaintType.Description,
        CreationDate = c.CreationDate,
        Customer = c.Customer,
        Description = c.Description,
        Id = c.Id,
        SequenceNumber = c.SequenceNumber,
        Creator = c.Creator.Name
    });

    return result;
}
```

And this is my `ComplaintConfiguration`

```
public class ComplaintConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Complaint>
{
    public ComplaintConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.SequenceNumber).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
        Property(p => p.Description).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

You did not include definitions for your **ViewModel** classes, so let me first make sure we're on the same page regarding what you're actually trying to achieve.

It looks like you want to return some restricted set of fields when client requests a list of **Complaint** records from the parameters-less `Get()` but when the client requests a specific complaint from `Get([FromODataUri] int key)` method you want to include additional fields.

I modeled this assumption using the following hierarchy:

```
public class ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComplaintOverviewViewModel : ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComplaintViewModel : ComplaintOverviewViewModel
{
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

Ran tests, `GET /odata/ComplaintOData` returned a list with just **Id** and **Name** as expected, `GET /odata/ComplaintOData(1)` returned a single record containing **Details** in addition to the other two fields, also as expected.

I never had to change your code for the controller or the `WebApiConfig.cs` except the string parameter in `builder.EntitySet<ComplaintTypeViewModel>("ComplaintOData");` which had to match the ccontroller (you have `"ComplaintTypeOData"` in your code).

Since it worked, I tried to figure out how I can reproduce your 406. I've changed `ComplaintViewModel` to extend `ComplaintTypeViewModel` directly instead of extending `ComplaintOverviewViewModel` (note that I've just duplicated the `Name` property):

```
public class ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComplaintOverviewViewModel : ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComplaintViewModel : ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

This worked just fine as well.

The only way I could reproduce your 406 is when I changed the `ComplaintViewModel` to **not** have `ComplaintTypeViewModel` in its inheritance hierarchy at all:

```
public class ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComplaintOverviewViewModel : ComplaintTypeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComplaintViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

This finally gave me the 406 code from `GET /odata/ComplaintOData(1)` while `GET /odata/ComplaintOData` was still returning the list with **Id** and **Name** just fine.

So, it looks like as long as **all** of your **ViewModel** classes extend the same `T` from `builder.EntitySet<T>("name")` you can return any of them from `Get()` overloads in your controller. Please check how you define your **ViewModels**

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I had placed my code in an `ApiController`. Thanks to this, I can move the code back to the `ODataController`.

Comment: Unfortunately. I thought it worked, but it doesn't work when you query the model with odata. Could you try adding `?%24orderby=CreationDate%20desc&%24top=20&%24select=Id%2CSequenceNumber%2CCreationDate%2CCustomer%2CDescription&%24count=true` to the `Get()` method?

PS: In my opening post ComplaintTypeViewModel should be ComplaintViewModel

Comment: @Martijn, of course it works. You're escaping too much. You only need to escape the values of parameters, not names: `?$orderby=CreationDate%20desc&$top=20&$select=Id%2cSequenceNumber%2cCreationDate%2cCustomer%2cDescription&$count=true`

Comment: I don't get it to work. I've shortened the odata query to `?$orderby=CreationDate%20desc&$top=20&$count=true&$select=Id`. Things go wrong when I apply the `select`. Without the `select` everything works. The exception I get with `select` is `"The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type '<namespace>.ComplaintOverviewViewModel' and a check of type '<namespace>.ComplaintBaseViewModel' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries."`

Comment: Since I had to model your issue with my own code, I've used POCO arrays with `AsQueryable()`. That works with `$select`. If you're using EF behind your controller, it has its own implementation for `IQueryable` which might place other restrictions on your query. I cannot help you further without you providing more details on the internals of your implementation. There are answered questions in SO for that exception, for example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242729/linq-throwing-typeas-expression-with-input-of-type-1-and-check-of-type-2-is-not

Comment: @ Michael Domashchenko I've updated my opening post with some code. Does this help?

Comment: How are all your classes related? `class ComplaintOverviewViewModel : ComlaintBaseViewModel` and `class ComplaintViewModel : ComplaintBaseViewModel`? Which one do you use with the builder? `builder.EntitySet<ComplaintBaseViewModel>()`? You should use the base class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/complex-type-inheritance-in-odata-v4

Answer (score 0):

Create an umbrella class for both models and have your get methods return respectively what you want.

```
public class myMainModel
{
  public xxxOverviewViewModel x {get;set;}
  public xxxOverviewViewModel y {get;set;}
}

myMainModel Get()
{ 
  ....
  return myMainModel.x;
}

myMainModel Get( int key)
{ 
  ....
  return myMainModel.y;
}
```

Comment: @apemene I've tried this, but then I get an Exception saying that my model does not have a key defined. This Exception is thrown at `return builder.GetEdmModel` in the `WebApiConfig.cs`. `builder.EntitySet<myMainModel>("ComplaintOData");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to just remove `[EnableQuery]` from action

`public ComplaintViewModel Get([FromODataUri] int key)`

`EnableQueryAttribute` enable querying using the OData query syntax. It is acceptable for collections `IQueryable<>`. When you want to return single entity, don't use that attribute.

**UPDATES**

Also try to rename parameter `int key` to `id`

Comment: I have removed the `[EnableQuery]` attribute, but I still get the `406 Not Acceptable` message.

Comment: @Martijn How do you call it? See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191598/4275342

Comment: I've modifed the code so that it matches exactly as described, but I still get a 406 :/

Comment: I call it from the browser like this: `http://localhost:63538/odata/ComplaintOData(1)` I've also tried Postman, with a get request, same result.

Comment: @Martijn See my updates: Also try to rename parameter int key to id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155917/discussion-between-martijn-and-megatron).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion of replacing key with id, but with no success. One thing I noticed though is when I set a breakpoint in my controller, the breakpoint get hit, it is returning the data, and then I get a 406. This is using the `key` parameter name.